# Properly authenticating users and preventing attacks with jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, authentication, jwt

I was reading on the benefits of JSON web tokens and a few issues popped up for me.

You can set a token to expire after sometime. But if an attacker manages to steal the token from the client and use it? Is it possible to detect this event and give the appropriate response.

Also, when a token expires, you have to make another token and give it back  to the client. My question is what are the security benefits of this Vs just letting the client have a token that does not expire. Because if the attacker manages to.get the token once. There is a high chance they could get it again

Lastly, if you have to issue a new token everytime, how can you make sure that the user does not have to re sign in every time and all of this can be done in the background?

Thank you

Comment: "*when a token expires, you have to make another token and give it back to the client.*" - with the advantage that you can re-verify their credentials, or check whether their "session" has been removed, or whether they have been blocked or their access has been demoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can set a token to expire after sometime. But if an attacker manages to steal the token from the client and use it? Is it possible to detect this event and give the appropriate response.

If an attacker managers to steal the token from the client and use it, it is out of your control.  It means the client's computer has been compromised, and they have bigger things to worry about (key loggers, screen readers, etc...)

> Also, when a token expires, you have to make another token and give it back to the client. My question is what are the security benefits of this Vs just letting the client have a token that does not expire. Because if the attacker manages to.get the token once. There is a high chance they could get it again

Reissuing a new unique token ensures that the attacker would have to be always be aware of the newest token.  Again, if they are able to capture the token again, there is nothing you can do in this scenario.

> Lastly, if you have to issue a new token everytime, how can you make sure that the user does not have to re sign in every time and all of this can be done in the background?

You should not trust expired tokens (say a hacker found a 3 day old expired jwt for your site, it should not allow him to log).  I would suggest you determine the sensitivity of your site and figure out if it should have a 10 minute, 1 hour, or 24 hour expiry.  I wouldn't do more than 24 hours.

If the token is expired, you should require the client to log in again.  If however, it isn't expired, perhaps you can consider issuing a new token, replacing the old token, so that the expiry is renewed.

Comment: Right. So generally. Everytime, the user accesses.the server. I should resend a new token that updates the time of expiry. Is this a correct approach? If it.is. if the attacker gets.the token, they can theoretically use the API for as long as they want

Comment: The attacker will be able to use the API for as long as the token isn't expired.  Once it is, they cant.  So if they renew every hour or so, theoretically they will be able to use the API as long as they want.  Is it likely?  Probably not.  They'd first have to identify and know the how the backend works for them to reliably continue to have access to your APIs.